# exportfs; invalid ip address

Tags: autofs

rhel 7.9 setting up autofs for CentOS 7 client. Every time I run exportfs -ra I see the exportfs: invalid ip address for 10.0.0.2. /etc/exports looks like /opt somehost:/opt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using rhel 7.9. Setting up autofs for CentOS client. I have file system information set up in /etc/exports. Each time I run exportfs -ra, nothing exports and I get the error message: exportfs: invalid IP address for XXX.XXX.XXX..XXX
/etc/exportfs looks like /opt/XXX.XXX client:/opt/XXX.XXX. I'm not sure if that gives any more information.

Comment: yeah sorry, if you have an error about IP addresses, but can't tell us IP addresses, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

`exportfs` is needed on the NFS server, not on the NFS client. You cannot remotely dictate some other server to export its filesystems.

[The error message "Invalid IP address"](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git;a=blob;f=support/export/client.c;h=79164fef0a8fe71721570ed6a1e2d8759067f817;hb=HEAD#l206) appears only `exportfs` is trying to parse a subnetwork address. It seems your `/etc/exports` syntax is not correct.

If you want to share `/opt` to 10.0.0.2, a valid `/etc/exports` entry might look like:

```
/opt        10.0.0.2(rw)
```

For more examples, run `man 5 exports` and look for the `EXAMPLE` paragraph.

You cannot specify the mounting location the NFS client should use in `/etc/exports`: where the client will mount the share is client's own business, as far as the NFS server is concerned.

Since the colon can be part of a IPv6 address, `exportfs` seems to be parsing your client specification `somehost:/opt` as a possible IPv4 or IPv6 subnetwork address, because it contains a slash. But the part before the slash is not a valid IP or IPv6 address, and the part after the slash is not a prefix length number nor a valid IPv4 netmask, and so you get the "Invalid IP address" error.

The line

```
/opt somehost:/opt
```

looks more like it should be part of an AutoFS *direct map* file on the AutoFS client: it is completely inappropriate for `/etc/exports`. You should not be running `exportfs -ra` on the AutoFS client at all: that command should instead be run on the NFS server whose shares you wish to automount.

Comment: Thank you so much, telcoM!!